# How to use a SubString method with string array in java

Tags: java, android

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int count;
            String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" ;


            String[] fileName = params;
            String a = fileName.toString();
            String b = a.substring(20,25);
            destination+=b;


            try {

                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();

                int lengthofFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Length of file: " + lengthofFile);

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destination);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthofFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            return null;
        }
```

my param variable will contain the url link which is "http://ledeveloper.in/ep123BCA.pdf" and i want to cut that url..the desire string which i want "ep123BCA.pdf".

But when i run this code the substring Method will always give me a different sub string how to solve that problem.

please help and thanx in advance.

Comment: use split method `String[] parts= url.split("/");` it will split the url into 3 or 4 parts, last one is the file name , this is a one way

Comment: not working for me that give me a same garbage name of the downloaded file. :(

Answer (score 2):

Use `lastIndexOf` to get the file name from the URL:

```
String b = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
fileName=a.substring(a.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is (if the first part of the url never change)

```
a.substring(22)
```

This should split the string this way:

```
the part cut out = http://ledeveloper.in/
a = ep123BCA.pdf
```

Comment: It is a solution, but it's not flexible enough.

Comment: That is most certainly correct :)

Comment: giving a garbage name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://ledeveloper.in/ep123BCA.pdf";
         String file = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

This line replace with your code.